# How to delete or change VPN profile configs in ios Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, vpn, nevpnmanager

in my app, I will fetch VPN profile config from server and create a VPN model.
at first I easily install profile if there isn't previous profile config.
but if profile config changed I have to change installed profile config such as server address and etc. 
how can I change or delete previous VPN profile or what's the best case to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEVPNManager includes a [`removeFromPreferences` API that you can use](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406202-removefrompreferenceswithcomplet?language=objc) to remove your VPN configuration.

If you change the profile (e.g. the [`protocolConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1406457-protocolconfiguration?language=objc)), you can also call [`saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nevpnmanager/1405985-savetopreferenceswithcompletionh?language=objc).